# Changing class name of a span inside a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Having multiple div's which contains multiple span's like this

```
<div class = "cw">
   <span class = "ci"></span>
   <span class = "d1"></span>
</div>

<div class = "cw">
   <span class = "ci"></span>
   <span class = "d2"></span>
</div>
```

I want to make a jquery such that I want to change the class name of the first span from the first div. How can i be more specific with the selector such that my jquery changes only my first span class.

The condition is that the div classes cannot be changed.

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: Did you have try something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:first`](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)/[`:eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector

```
$('.cw:first .ci').doSomething()
$('.cw:eq(0) .ci').doSomething()
```

```js
$('.cw:first .ci').addClass('red');
$('.cw:eq(1) .ci').addClass('blue');
```

```css
.red {
  color: red
}

.blue {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cw">
  <span class="ci">1</span>
  <span class="d1">2</span>
</div>

<div class="cw">
  <span class="ci">1</span>
  <span class="d2">2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: oki but if I need to change the second one? or the third one?

Comment: @MarcMoldovan, You can use `:eq()` with index

Comment: But i don't know which one it is. Let's say that they are generated dynamic

Comment: @MarcMoldovan, You need to elaborate update the question with your exact problem

Comment: @MarcMoldovan check my answer. If you wish to select the second or third `<div>` then you can use `:nth-of-type(2)` or `:nth-of-type(3)` instead of `:first`. Similarly for the spans you may use `:nth-child(2)` or `:nth-child(3)` instead of `:first-child`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `:first` selector.

If you want to change second element, use `:nth-child(2)'`

```js
$('.cw:first').find('span:first').text('first elem');
$('.cw:first').find('span:nth-child(2)').text('second elem');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cw">
  <span class="ci"></span>
  <span class="d1"></span>
</div>

<div class="cw">
  <span class="ci"></span>
  <span class="d2"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may first remove the class you don't want by this: `$("div:first span:first-child").removeClass("className");` then add the new class to the same element with: `$("div:first span:first-child").addClass("className");`

Answer (score 0):

To change class of first span use [:first](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) selector or [:eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

Like using first selector:

```
$('div.cw:first').find('span:first').addClass('new_class');
```

Or using eq selector

```
$('.cw:eq(0)').find('span:eq(0)').addClass('new_class');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```js
$('.cw:first').find('span:first').removeClass('ci').addClass('newClass');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1
/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cw">
  <span class="ci">ci</span>
  <span class="d1">d1</span>
</div>

<div class="cw">
  <span class="ci">ci</span>
  <span class="d2">d2</span>
</div>
```